# Receiving List View Threshold error with no lists containing over 5000 items?

Tags: 2013, error, restore, list-view-threshold

1) No list in my entire site collection is over 2000 items.

2) Throttling for lists is set to 5000 items.

Why, when I export my site collection and import into my development farm, do I receive a List View Threshold error?

I've done this process a million times and now it's not working...Its driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the "List View Lookup Threshold" instead of the "List View Threshold" as the error stated. Once I upped the lookup threshold from 12 on both my live and dev environments, it worked like a charm.